# link from webbrowser to ScintillaNET editor in a same c# form?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, scintilla

I am new to ScintillaNET. I am using webbrowser and scintillaNET editor component in the same form. My task is when i click a link in webbrowser it should link to a text which is in editor. Any help and suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.